# How to add custom toolbar to UIPickerView Control?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I want to add a custom toolbar at the top of the UIPickerView control. I did this on Keyboard but not able to do with UIPickerView.

Nishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a toolBar by IBoutlet and set its y coordinate to 100 or more than view's height. then in particular action change y coordinate accordingly. this is done via animation.

You also use this with keyboard .

by using
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) note
and
-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) note

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIToolBar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
        [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneBtnTapped:)];

        toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
        barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [popoverView addSubview:toolBar];

        [popoverView addSubview:pickerView];
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a custom view and added a done button on that along with picker view.

Thanks